# grep preceding line just for one specific pattern

Tags: regex, linux, grep

given an example log file like:

```
interesting stuff
App: 123 blob
some text
other text
ERROR could not find file XYZ
other really cool stuff
App: 123 blob
some text
other text
ERROR stdout blocked
```

I want to grep the line with 'ERROR' and 'App:' plus the line before 'App:'.
With multiple search-patterns and -B 1 i get the matching lines plus the respective line before:

```
grep -B 1 -e '^App:.*' -e '.*ERROR.*'

interesting stuff
App: 123 blob
--
other text
ERROR could not find file XYZ
other really cool stuff
App: 123 blob
--
other text
ERROR stdout blocked
```

(i also don't know where the '--' are coming from)
but my desired output is:

```
interesting stuff
App: 123 blob
ERROR could not find file XYZ
other really cool stuff
App: 123 blob
ERROR stdout blocked
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep`'s `-B 1` option would apply to all expressions. You can use `awk` in this case:

```
$ awk '/App/ {print line;print} {line=$0} /ERROR/' file 
interesting stuff
App: 123 blob
ERROR could not find file XYZ
other really cool stuff
App: 123 blob
ERROR stdout blocked
$
```